# Form with List Box and Text Box

Tags: list, forms, box

I have a form that has a list box using fields from a table. The fields are labeled Line Numbers. On the form I have a separate Text box for line size. The Line size also has a field in the table associated with the line number. The goal on the form is to select the Line Number in the list box and the line size show up in the text box.

Thanks for the help.

Only added the list box and have no issues so far.

Comment: Please share the code you have written for [minimum reproducible example] (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and what you have tried so for.